# How big would the Akashic Records be?

Tags: biology

The Akashic Records are a catalog of all events, thoughts and feelings that have happened on Earth.  Supposedly its stored on the etheric plane.

I'd like to have this information existing in the the material universe of my World.  My thought is that these Akashic records would be encoded into the DNA of bacteria.

At a rate of 1.8 bits per nucleotide, how much bacterial mass would be needed to house 4.5 billion years worth of the Akashic Records?

(Edit)
The record should only pertain to the events that happen to living creatures that orginate on earth.  Resolution would be at the organismal level, not inter or intra cellular. The cells that host the library would not record their own actions.

Assume that the data increases according to a pareto distribution comensurate with the complexity of life, and humans are the largest contributers.

Our current digital data  is at 2.7 zetabytes in total and 2.5 exabytes generated daily.  50% of humanity is online, so a rough estimate says that a human population of 7.2 billion produces >5 exabytes of data.

With the Current level of bacteria and archaea at a total of 77 gigatons of carbon, would there be enough storage space for the Akashic Records?

Comment: What's the granularity/scope of an "event"? Is a heartbeat an event? Is an action potential fired from a neuron an event? What about a phosphate group binding to an enzyme? You might have a lot of events!

Comment: What kind of resolution are we looking at here? If we're recording every particle's exact position and momentum (defenestrating Heisenberg in the process), virtual and real, at yoctosecond time scales, then we're going to be looking at a *lot* of bacteria.

Comment: Apart from the above asked clarification, what is the nucleotide/bacteria ratio? You specify the bit/nucleotide, but ask about bacteria mass.

Comment: @Qami I was curious too.   Apparently they also include [all organisms thoughts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records), which makes me think it's at least atomic-scale.  If we knew mechanistically how all of these arose it would allow for some level of data compression, but still...

Comment: Ok so we are looking at something that possible might have an exponential growth rate and some limit, spans billions of years and is saved onto carriers that tend to rod away in something like 10000 years time or so, Nothing easier than that.

Comment: Not a full answer yet: S Cellulosum has the largest bacterial genome at [13Mbp](https://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?s=n&v=8&id=104469) and while I couldn't find precise numbers for this strain, bacterial cultures top out around [1e7 / mL](http://book.bionumbers.org/what-is-the-concentration-of-bacterial-cells-in-a-saturated-culture/).  That's 1.8*1e7*1.3e7, or 2.34e14 bits/mL. Regardless, even at protein-level resolution, they encode less data [than their existence requires](http://book.bionumbers.org/how-many-proteins-are-in-a-cell/)

Comment: How would you locate the proper bacteria to retrieve the data? And how many poor sods must toil way writing all that data onto bacteria? And should all that support infrastructure be included in the size?

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows I don't think this set needs to contain itself. Akashic Records (according to OP) list events that happened on Earth, specifically. Bacteria could be stored anywhere.

Comment: @Qami You're quite correct, I misread the question, comment deleted.

Comment: wow thanks so much for the comments, really helped me focus my thoughts on this, i hope the edits answer the general questions

Comment: Not to go all zen on everyone, but...  The universe as it exists across space and time IS itself the minimum required data space needed to record all of its relevant characteristics and events. For your case, focusing in on just the space occupied by the planet Earth during the subset of all time when the Earth actually existed, can be accurately recorded by an object no smaller than one Earth and no shorter lived that the Earth itself.  Take this minimum mass/time requirement and multiply it by the efficiency of your bacterial storage technique and you have the amount of etheric space needed.

Comment: @Henry Taylor the holographic principle, which i think is that the universe is existing flattened on the surface of a blackhole, which is more or less data compression

Comment: @Eloc, Yes black holes may store information on what they consume but the spagettification process of feeding any object into a black hole seems to loose much of the details such as where particular sub-objects were located on the whole, relative to each other.  Black holes are also, probably just a snapshot of the single moment (stretched out across deep time) when the object entered the black hole.  The OP is looking for a more organized and comprehensive across planetary lifespan accounting of the Earth.  Assuming no indeces or bookmarks, my comment above answers that need.

Comment: I found this in the VTR queue, but voted to leave it closed.  The phrase, "all events, thoughts, and feelings" is the deal killer.  Humans may be producing 5 exabytes daily, but that's ***no where near*** all the events, thoughts, and feelings of humanity.  Not even close.  Not close on the order of 10^999.  The scope of data generation makes the bacteria the size of a galaxy and my guess is as good as anyone (and everyone) else's.  This question is interesting, but it needs to be seriously scoped.  As in well-defined boundaries, which it doesn't have.

Comment: @ JBH thanks for that, i was wondering what other edits to make.  I do have a narrative idea for parsing down the absolute immensity of data, some thing to the effect of sapient species becoming cataloging "bookkeepers", but i wanted to keep the question within length.

Comment: Am voting to reopen, as this seems to be a pretty good worldbuilding query.  I'm not sure why bacteria are involved, and I'm not sure why the entire history of the cosmos is involved --- the [Akashic Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records) is *a compendium of all human events, thoughts, words, emotions, and intent ever to have occurred in the past, present, or future*. Pretty much find out the total number of humans & multiply by the data generation inconstant and Bob's your uncle.  Seems pretty reasonable for a geopoet to wish to locate the Record in the physical world. I did!

Comment: And... I'm voting to close again after this [very similar question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/248661/80336) was posted. How much the answerers had to provide relevant details in place of the querent is a strong hint that the query lacked details (and focus). How much place should feelings take? Do we include animal thoughts (and if so how should we encode it?). That's only a few examples among sooooo many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is impossible to know for sure, but you can do some estimations**

So we we are going to treat is like a Fermi problem, and do some broad estimations and hopefully end up in an order of magnitude of the correct answer. These numbers assume we are storing text. Audio or video will see this number spike dramatically (which is why we store so much now).

- Each human needs 100 pages of text a day to describe all their actives to a detailed, yet reasonable level.
- Each page has 2 Kilobytes of text (so 200 KB per day)
- Each human lives for on average 10000 days
- That's 2,000,000 KB or 2 GB per person
- About 100,000,000,000 people have ever lived
- That's 200,000,000,000 GB of data or 200 Exabytes

If you would like to add animals, we will assume that the last 200,000 years of humans is similar to the amount generated by all animals during previous years, leading to 4,500,000‬ Exabytes of data or 4,500 Zettabyes.

A gram of bacteria can hold at least 1 Exabyte of data, so you would need about 10,000 pounds of bacteria. All bacteria on the planet weighs far more than this. So yeah. You're good.

Comment: Even if you include animals and plants, or assume a person needs significantly more than 100 pages (not unreasonable, if you are going to describe every factor that the person weighted in making every decision they did) you still only add a few orders of magnitude to this estimate.  Given that Earth is estimated to have something like 70 gigatons of bacteria, this is in fact perfectly doable.  I wouldn't have believed it until I looked at the math.

Answer (score 1):

(first note; volume requirement is not very relevant since it depends on storage medium. Let's go with mass requirement)

earth_mass * number_of_snapshots

If your snapshot frequency is planck time (smallest observable distinct time interval) you will need the mass of the earth, multiplied by the instances of planck time that have passed since you started recording. At this scale, the earth's mass doesn't even matter since the planck scale outweights it so much, the result essentially rounds down to 10^51 kg, which, you are surprisingly lucky, is two orders of magnitude less than the mass of ordinary matter inside the observable universe! So, this is actually possible (albeit unfeasible...)

Nasu, you sly fox, you knew your math!

---

As you can see from the above, any compression that doesn't allow you to reduce the snapshot frequency won't have a meaningful effect. To make this more compact you have to reduce the frequency at which you are recording. If you concede that all meaningful "events" take a minimum of, for example, one nanosecond to execute, you can save quite a lot of mass.

Comment: I dunno. Some compression algorithms would shave vast quantities of data out of the picture. As you know their speed, energy and assorted vectors you could record all photon positions as wave information rather than discrete particle positions, for example, though you might get the odd decompression artefact like light appearing to ‘decide’ which path it takes... Wait... Wait a darn second...