# How many books would you need to write all of the world's historical moments and the significant characters behind it? (Using earth as an example)

Tags: knowledge

There is a secret library in my world that contains all of the the world's known and unknown moments that had happened before whether if it is any scale of wars or an animal going extinct, the library contains it all, but for it to have this many books, how big should the library be? Would a city-size library be enough?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the moments are unknown, how can they be written in a book?

Comment: How long is the world's history?  What constitutes a "historical moment" - does a mountain getting created by volcanic activity and worn down to the size of a hill before the first creature existed in the primordial sludge count?  What about a small hill?  What about a pool of primordial sludge that doesn't quite evolve life? And so on...

Comment: That entirely depends on what is the intended meaning of the phrase historical moments. A rough timeline of the history of pre-imperial Rome fits in half a page. Mommsen's *Römische Geschichte* covers only pre-imperial Rome, has three large volume, and is little more than a high-level overview. The *Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum* is currently at volume XVII and, of course, contains only those inscriptions which have been preserved, and not all of these. In a good library you will find half a shelf of books about the battle of Actium -- one battle, which was over in half a day.

Comment: What defines history?  Let's leave aside primordial sludge - would a book entirely about the air currents that lead to a hurricane be "history"?  History is fractal - every moment can be broken down into sub-moments, each of which has their own history leading up to them.

Comment: The answer to this question depends solely on how you set the threshold for when a piece of information is significant enough to include in it. For exapmle, I guess you want to track leadership changes of countries. What about leadership changes of cities? Towns? Individual homesteads? I voted to close the question until significance criteria are added.

Comment: Do note that most of the time, [Akashic records](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records) (what you're trying to size) in lots of stories are just made look huge and people just say it contains "billions" of books. That's because it would contains too much data to be processed by someone, like you can't see what billions of dollars means (not talking recording it requires magic). This in turns set the needs to be detailed to still be plausible low.

Comment: Closely related : [How big would the akashic records be (with bacteria)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/153677/80336).

Comment: If you really tried to condense world history down to just the most significant events, you could cover it with [a 20 minute youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuCn8ux2gbs).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. As said history is fractal. Therefore you need your books to be fractal as well. A page, a paragraph, a quote, a word should be able to be opened to bring up more pages. That is hard to do with paper books. But straightforward with digital documents. The presentation of this digital information would be your library and it could be anything you want: HTML pages, virtual reality, computer generated dreams...

Comment: I think this query is sufficiently detailed to be answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two variables that make this impossible to fully answer:

- What is the threshold of importance for an event to be included?
- How much detail should be given about each event?

We could look at is some orders of magnitude for the two different types of "history" you mention:

### Human history

The number of "events" that happens probably scales roughly with the number of people considered - in a year of today's world of ~8 billion people, there are multiple large-scale wars comprising dozens of battles, multiple election campaigns and political scandals, hundreds of significant deaths, and so on; in a year of the hunter-gather society of the paleolithic, there might be only a handful of conflicts. We could perhaps guess at an average of one page per human lifetime. The [total number of humans who've ever lived](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimates_of_historical_world_population) is estimated at around **100 billion** over the last 50 thousand years or so.

The Wikipedia category "2019 events by month" (I figure the totals for the "pandemic years" might be unusual) and its sub-categories [contain 17 thousand articles](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=25554667). That's roughly one for every 500 thousand people, *per year* - close to **one for every 5000 people over their lifetime**.

There are surely plenty of things that would count as "events" that don't have a Wikipedia article, so my initial guess of **one event per thousand humans** doesn't sound far off. That alone is **100 million events**.

### Biological history

The concept of "species" is an entirely man-made one, without one clear definition that can apply to all types of life, and all scales of context. [The Wikipedia article on biodervisity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_biodiversity) quotes wildly varying figures for total number of species alive today, but gives an order of magnitude for *eukaryotic species* as about 10 million. Based on the idea that "more than 99 percent of all species that ever lived on Earth are estimated to be extinct", we can guess that maybe **1 billion species have gone extinct**, over the last 2 to 3 billion years.

### Encyclopedia size

Our estimates give us counts between 100 million and 1 billion "events". If we assume a short encyclopedia article for each, we can estimate the size of a printed copy.

As of this writing, [Wikipedia has about 6 million articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_of_Wikipedia), estimated to [fill 3000 volumes, on 17 bookshelves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_in_volumes). Our counts are between 20 and 200 times as large - **300 to 3000 bookshelves** holding around **60 thousand to 600 thousand volumes**.

### Library size

For comparison, one of the largest libraries in the world is the [US Library of Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Congress), which holds more than **30 million books**, among other collections. That's 50 times the largest estimate we've come up with so far.

That collection is mostly housed in three large buildings in Washington, D.C. - nowhere near the scale of "a city-sized library".

### Conclusion

A single copy of an encyclopedia with a brief of summary of every human and species-level "event" *could* fit into a single large building. However, that could easily expand by several orders of magnitude if it included more detail, or more categories of event.

Answer (score 3):

> And there are also many other things which Jesus did, the which, if
> they should be written every one, I suppose that even the world itself
> could not contain the books that should be written. Amen. John 21:25

### The World is Big, Lots of Stuff Happens in It

If you were to record every "moment" of a single person's life, each nibble of food, each muscle twinge or twitch, it could fill a library.  If you added commentary pointing out context, it would balloon even more.

There have been billions of people.

But a billion libraries intricately detailing the lives of every person wouldn't cover the tree falling in the forest when no one was around, the life of each ant in each anthill (quadrillions of ants), and a list of other things which list might alone fill a library.

The world could not contain a library which covered its entire history, unless it left most details out.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm - so using Wikipedia as a Baseline - they have (at time of writing) 58,747,275 Articles and they estimate that if they were to be put into volumes like the Encyclopedia Britannica - that would be 2,657 Volumes or 14 Book shelves.

Easily achievable in an average city library. Hell, I've even been to hole-in-the-wall second hand book shops with more than 14 book shelves.

However...

If I look at an article for say a certain mid-century Austrian Dictator, his article is 43 pages (single side) of A4, so let's say 22 double sided pages.

I have it, on quite good authority, that there is more information about said person than merely 22 double sided pages. There are countless books, all with original information, speculation, reasoned conjecture etc. etc.

There are a plethora of other historical figures for whom the same could easily be said.

If you limit yourself to the detail provided by Wikipedia (which for *most* things provides a good overview) and you use article linking (another great way that you save on space, avoiding the duplication of information) - then yes, it's easily possible to have a pretty good record of history and historical events.

But such a repository wouldn't be considered comprehensive. Many a YouTube historian has recorded rants about Wikipedia glossing over a lot of nuance and context and deep information for subjects that whilst may not disprove the information per se in Wikipedia, can certainly cast it in a different and less favorable light.

Comment: And must a library use physical books? What if the data are digitalized? Compressed size of Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_of_Wikipedia) is a mere 22.14Gb (exluding media).

Comment: I agree that for many things, such as the biographies of obscure singers and the line-ups of soccer sides in presumably notable matches, Wikipedia does a good job. Unfortunately, history is not one of those things, and as for good *outlines* of history Wikipedia doesn't even know what they might be. (This is by policy. Wikipedia is not a real encyclopedia, but rather a mindless summary of secondary literature. It is not possible to write a good outline of history under this restriction.)

Comment: @KCWong In your world, you can. But here the querent was quite clear they wanted physical books in a physical library :).

Answer (score 1):

### The Akashic Records

There is no way of saying how many books this would take because there is no way of deciding on a single threshold of information.  In theory, your library could be so vast and detailed that it would collapse into a black hole and consume the entire universe growing until there are no future events left to record... or it could be just a few book shelves, just depending.

Instead let's try looking at this from another angle.  How can you have a library with an infinite amount of knowledge, not consume an infinite space and mass?

According to Theosophy, the Akashic Records are a non-physical recording of everything that ever has and ever will happen, anywhere in the history of the universe.  This "record" exists in a transdimensional state of existence that can in theory be accessed from anywhere through careful meditation, but it takes great wisdom and training to discern information conjured up from the Akashic Records from one's own desires and imagination.

So, if your library itself is transdimensional, then the question of size only comes down to what you need to be able to access it.  Your "library" could a monastery full of wisemen who devote thier lives to meditation, answering people's questions or writing down books from record.  Or it could be a single magical book that acts as a focus, filling its pages with information from the record. Or it could be a place that you go when you meditate where the image of a library is just your brain's representation of the infinite knowledge at its disposal.  Or, it could be a special computer system that taps into the record and delivers information like ChatGPT.